# In React, how to test the click event in child that's inside a parent element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm doing unit-testing on a `component` child element, for a React app using Jest, the issue is I cannot test if a function has been called or not when the child element is clicked. The function is mocked with `jest.fn()`. But I still get this error `Expected mock function to have been called.`.

#### Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Panel extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    title: 'No data',
    info: 'Please add some info!.'
  }

  handleRemove() {
    alert('Panel should be removed!');
  }

  handleShare(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Panel info can shared on social media.');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panel col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" className="panel-remove-btn" onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove</a>
        <div>
          <h3 className="panel-title">{this.props.panel.title}</h3>
          <p className="panel-info">{this.props.panel.info}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a className="panel-share-btn btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleShare}>Share</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

#### Component unit-test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Panel from '../Panel/Panel';

describe('Panel', () => {
  let panel,
    panelData = {
      title: 'Sabrina girls!!',
      info: 'Some Sabrina best kitchen dishes'
    };

  beforeEach(() => {
    panel = shallow(<Panel panelDate={panelData} />);
  });

  it('renders as intended', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Panel panelData={panelData} />),
      json = component.toJSON();

    expect(json).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders Panel title', () => {
    expect(panel.find('.panel-title').text()).toEqual('Sabrina girls!!');
  });

  it('renders Panel information', () => {
    expect(panel.find('.panel-info').text()).toEqual('Some Sabrina best kitchen dishes');
  });

  it('should remove the Panel', () => {
    const handleRemove = jest.fn();

    expect(panel.find('.panel-remove-btn').length).toEqual(1);

    // accessing the child element and simulate a click
    panel.first().find('.panel-remove-btn').simulate('click');

    expect(handleRemove).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <= "handleRemove" is not called even though I've defined it above and simulated a click event!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create a spy that is never used. You need to test `Panel.prototype.handleRemove`. So before rendering you need to mock it like this, using [`jest.spyOn`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) :

```
const handleRemove = jest.spyOn(Panel.prototype, 'handleRemove');
expect(handleRemove).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

or

```
Panel.prototype.handleRemove = jest.spy()
expect(handleRemove).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but then the original function will not been called.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasKöberle for responding. But I use your answer, I get an error `TypeError: jest.spyOn is not a function`. The funniest is `jest.spyOn()` does exist in the `jest` object. I'm lost!! Do you know why?

Comment: What version of jest do you use?

Comment: I'm using version `18.1.0`. I got it from the `create-react-app` CLI.

Comment: Ah, its available at available in Jest 19.0.0

Comment: Sorry about this but it's still not working now I get `TypeError: jest.spy is not a function`